# How to create a dojo 1.9 slideshow

Tags: dojo, slideshow

This is (part of) a web page. For some reason, I fail to get the slide-show operational. Can you help me fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang='fr'>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1' />
    <link href='../dojo-release-1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' />
  </head>
  <body class='claro'>
  <script>
    dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: true}
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../dojo-release-1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js'>
      </script> 
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    require(["dojo", "dojo/parser", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojox/image/SlideShow"]);
    var imageData= {
        identifier: "imageUrl",
        items: [
              { imageUrl: "http://mysyte.net/photos/f1.jpg"},
              { imageUrl: "http://mysyte.net/photos/f2.jpg"},
              { imageUrl: "http://mysyte.net/photos/f3.jpg"},
              { imageUrl: "http://mysyte.net/photos/f4.jpg"}
            ]
    };              
  </script>
  <div data-dojo-type='dojo/store/Memory' data-dojo-props='data:imageData' data-dojo-id='imageStore'></div>
  <div data-dojo-type='dojox/image/SlideShow' id='slideshow1' data-dojo-id='imageShow'
      data-dojo-props='store: imageStore, noLink: true, autoStart:true, imageWidth:770, imageHeight:345, slideshowInterval: 5'>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?? Can you help me fixing it? Thanks!

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: No error, but nothing happens. I can see in Firebug that the elements are there, because the opacity changes when hovering the mouse over the area. But that's all, no images are displayed. If you have access to an Apache server (or WAMP, LAMP), you could give it a try maybe? I could give a link to my test website, but I'm not sure if it's allowed. It's essentially identical.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang='fr'>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1' />
    <link href='../dojo-release-1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' />
  </head>
  <body class='claro'>
  <script>
    dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: true}
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../dojo-release-1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var imageData= {
        identifier: "imageUrl",
        items: [
              { imageUrl: "http://mysyte.net/photos/f1.jpg"},
              { imageUrl: "http://mysyte.net/photos/f2.jpg"},
              { imageUrl: "http://mysyte.net/photos/f3.jpg"},
              { imageUrl: "http://mysyte.net/photos/f4.jpg"}
             ]
    };
    require(["dojo", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dojox/image/SlideShow", "dijit/registry"], function(dojo, ItemFileReadStore, SlideShow, registry) {
            dojo.ready(function() {
              registry.byId('slideshow1').setDataStore(imageStore, {})
            })
        });
  </script>
  <div data-dojo-type='dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore' data-dojo-props='data:imageData' data-dojo-id='imageStore'></div>
  <div data-dojo-type='dojox/image/SlideShow' id='slideshow1' data-dojo-id='imageShow'
      data-dojo-props='autoStart:true, showTitle: false, noLink: true, hasNav: false, imageWidth:770, imageHeight:345, fixedHeight: true, slideshowInterval: 5'>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apparently, the SlideShow object in dojo has some bugs/inconsistencies. I even had to modify the dojox/image/SlideShow.js file. The clues I found here: http://petergragert.info/dojo/demo/PKHG_won_22feb.html and in http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Dojo-1-8-SlideShow-Problem-tp3991064.html